# обЪясните по порядку что делает эта программа шаг за шагом

Tags: python

```
N = int (input ('Введите число: '))
 
for d in range (1, N // 2 + 1) :
  if N % d == 0 :
    print (d, ' ', sep = '', end = '')
print (N)
```

Comment: Возможно стоит немного разобраться в синтаксисе питона и обратиться за помощью с более конкретным вопросом? Дам подсказку: эта программа считывает число и далее в цикле если выполняется некоторое условие печатает некоторое значение.

Comment: byte код данной программы: `e\x00e\x01d\x00\x83\x01\x83\x01Z\x02e\x03d\x01e\x02d\x02\x1a\x00d\x01\x17\x00\x83\x02D\x00] Z\x04e\x02e\x04\x16\x00d\x03k\x02r\x1ee\x05e\x04d\x04d\x05d\x05d\x06\x8d\x04\x01\x00q\x1ee\x05e\x02\x83\x01\x01\x00d\x07S\x00`

Comment: когда минусуете, вы вспомните свой первый вопрос на SO и вообще первые шаги в программировании

Answer (score 4):

1. Программа просит пользователя ввести целое число N, которое затем сохраняется в переменной N.
2. Затем программа выполняет цикл for, который перебирает числа от 1 до (N // 2 + 1).
3. В теле цикла for проверяется, является ли текущее число d делителем числа N.
4. Если d является делителем N, то оно выводится на экран без перехода на новую строку.
5. По завершении цикла for, переменная N выводится на экран в новой строке.

Эта программа выводит все делители числа N, включая N само.